# UK visa refusal V4.2, want to make sure it doesn't happen again

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, uk-citizens

Our situation has changed since his visa refusal, but is it enough to satisfy an ECO?

My husband came to the UK for the birth of our daughter but was subsequently refused a UK visit visa in 2016. At the time I had just given birth and couldn't fly to him. We didn't need a settlement visa as he had just set up a business in Morocco, and I wasn't working, so I didn't satisfy the requirements. I flew to him when I was fit and well again with the kids.

I am no longer in the UK. We are both residing in Brunei. I work and he takes care of our 2 young children. We want to visit the UK in September to see family, and do a little sightseeing for a week. I'm terrified of another refusal against his name.

I obviously didn't include sufficient explanation in my cover letter the first time.

Your help/advice would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the history of UK refusals I've seen on this site and other places, it seems for UK the most important criteria is the applicant's financial circumstances. This is also a reason explained in your refusal letter, so if your financial circumstances improved significantly - such as the level where you can easily afford a trip to UK - this might be sufficient for approval.

An evidence that you are both settled in Brunei (such as a property lease agreement for one year or so, employment contract etc) would also help establishing the fact that you're not moving back to UK together, and only trying to visit.